# How would I automate repetitive tasks in Android?

Tags: automation, scripts, automate

There are many tasks I do repetitively, like connect a Bluetooth headset or connect to a hotspot.  How do I typically "code" this?  How do I execute?
Is there a consistent library or package manager, or do I have to collect from everywhere?

Any community projects?
Anything that works consistently over several platforms?
Is there some framework to execute over several devices?
(In the Bluetooth example I might want to disconnect other devices at the same time)

Comment: I think you can use automation apps to accomplish what you asked. However, the example given is not detailed enough (what other devices or actions do you want to automate? ) for me to be 100% sure.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Use case: disconnect existing sound devices connect to a known already paired Bluetooth Headset with spesific settings.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio In the above case it could be useful to have other devices disconnect from the headset at the same time (Mostly Android, also Wondows)

Answer (score 3):

A great app for that is Automate. I've used it with great success. There are a few plugins that exist; you may or may not need them

The main app is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

Based on your use case, you may want [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate.ext.network),  [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate.ext.location) and maybe [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate.ext.settings) extensions but it all depends on how you use the main app

Comment: This showed up when I googled the issue.  I kindof thought that scripting should be more powerful, and also that a community project could do more (Like supporting different devices)

Comment: @Olav for what it is, it works really well

Comment: Please note that the solution from the other answer is **not** free. If that's your thing, though, go for it

Comment: Thanks.  On a first look, it looks more like a community thing?  I don't mind paying, but a community project should be better for this purpose.  (And also it should be mentioned)

Comment: @Olav if I'm remembering correctly that is true

Answer (score 2):

The best one I've ever come across is Tasker. It isn't necessarily coding but you do get to script your tasks in a scratch fashion. Although I don't see how it might be different from Automate which is another great choice.

Tasks created for tasker can also be download from the internet of which [Tasker Wiki](http://tasker.wikidot.com/profile-index) is my favourite source.

Comment: The true strength of Tasker is the number of third party apps with links to Tasker.